# Vue.js directive mounting component: Injection not found

Tags: vue.js

So I'm trying to write a directive that will append a custom *error* component to an element.  Instead having to write `<i>` and `<span>` for everything I vee-validate, I want to just use a directive to auto-append my error message component.

Problem is, to get everything to use the same errorBag, I need to

```
@component({
  inject: {
    $validator: "$validator"
  }
})
```

In my custom component.  This works fine when I add the component to a page manually.  However, using a directive to mount my component I get a:

> [Vue warn]: Injection "$validator" not found.

Is there any way around this, or to make it work?

---

```
Vue.directive("test", {
  bind: function(el: any, binding: any, vnode: any){
    var instance = new error({
      propsData: { errorFor: el.id}
    })
    instance.$mount();
    el.after(instance.$el);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [Vue Guide: Provide/Inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject), Define default property for your inject, then it eliminates that warning..

As the guide says:

> the default property is used as **fallback** value

Below is one demo.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let test = Vue.component('v-test', {
  template: `<div>
  <h2>{{_test}} => {{getTodo()}}</h2>
  <h3>_validator is <span style="color:red">{{_validator ? 'provided' : 'not provided'}}</span></h3>
  </div>`,
  inject: {
    _test: {
      default: 'I am a test' //the default property is used as fallback value
    },
    _validator: {
      default() {//or we can use one factory method to warn the developers something.
        console.log('@warn@', 'parent does not provide validator')
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTodo: function() {
      return this._test
    }
  }
})
new test().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-test>Todos</v-test>
</div>
```

Below is one demo which pops up **the same error**.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let test = Vue.component('v-test', {
  template: `<div>
  </div>`,
  inject: {
    _test: 'I am a test' //no fallback
  }
})
new test().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-test>Todos</v-test>
</div>
```